# Get Component from react-router by path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How to get Component from react-router v4 by path?

I'm looking for a way to get the component that configured before, by path.

Forexample I have got this Route:

```
import React from 'react';
import UserScreen from './UserScreen';
...
<Route path='/user/:id' component={UserScreen}/>
```

Now I want to get the UserScreen Component by the path. Something like this:

```
getComponentByPath(path){
   // looking for this section 
}

render(){
  const component = getComponentByPath('/user/12');
  return (<component />);
}
```

I'm looking for the **Component object**.

Comment: A `Route` automatically renders its configured component when the browser location matches. You just have to create a `Link` or programmatically set the location to the path. That is exactly what `react-router` does.

Comment: @trixn Thanks for the response. I know that. Everybody knows that. It's the reason that anyone use react router. If you read again my question, I'm looking for the **component** in my code.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `BrowserRouter` react router v4 and render a component with corresponding route.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/user/:id' component={UserScreen}/> 
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

make a `UserScreen.js`:

```
class UserScreen extends Component {

render() {

    return (
    <div>hello world</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response. But I'm looking for the Component object